# How to read console input either space separated or newline separated in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-console

The input provided in my test is sometimes separated by  and sometimes by `\n`.

I want to store these inputs in an Array at the end.

Sample Input:

`1 2 3 4 5` (space separated)

`1\n2\n3\n4\n5` (newline separated)

I am able to `Split` the input in space separated but I have no clue how to do the newline separated.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Input");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputArray = input.Trim().Split(' ');
int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, int.Parse);
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you can use string.Split(' ') for the space separated.

Comment: I edited the question and mentioned how I am reading the space separated, I am also aware how to read newline separated but the challenge for me here is how i should handle this dynamically on the basis of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.Split Method (Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) for this.

---

```
.Split(new Char[] {' ', '\n' });
```

---

As you can see below, I've placed both `\n` and  in my input string. If you place a breakpoint after the assignment of `int[] numbers` you can see the `inputArray` was `Split` correctly:

---

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Input");
//var input = "1 2 3 4 5";
var input = "1\n2\n3\n4 5\n6 7 8\n9";
string[] inputArray = input.Trim().Split(new Char[] {' ', '\n' });
int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, int.Parse);
```

---

[image]

[[DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/TKZTO21223)

Comment: Hi @Brien, thank you for your answer, can you please also let me know how can I read newline separated input from console window? Sorry for delay as it was a weekend.

Comment: @PrashantJain How are you expecting the user to input the newline? If you attempt to force it, for example: "1\n2\n3\n", they become escaped like: "1\\n2\\n3\\n". I suppose you could `Replace()` them first like: `string[] inputArray = input.Trim().Replace(@"\n","").Split(new Char[] {' ', '\n' });`

Comment: In few of the test cases of the challenge, there automated system is trying to insert a number then pressing Enter then inserting next number on Console and to end this there automated system will hit enter twice.